# I am new to automation. I am researching on how can I create a Jenkins pipeline to build image in docker container?

Tags: automated-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

Its a TDD environment and I wanted to create a Jenkins file through code which different teams can pull in their projects and start writing tests.

Comment: Have you tried Googling for "jenkins create docker image"?

Answer (score 2):

The Jenkins site has info on setting up in a docker image. Docker also has github repos to provide examples of different setups. https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker